# Dynamic template page calling shared taxonomies CPT or Plugin post type : how to clone taxonomy for plugin + set up dynamic shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, meta-query

I'm building a website pro-bono for a friend searcher and making a template for 280 pages which will have the same structure as we want to be able to modify it in 1 place.

I do this with **elementor template builder**. In this template, I query several blocs of grid contents from different post types and it will display them depending on a **common category**.

For CPT, it's easy. I shared the native post category with ACF into the Page Type + into all my CPT, then I query dynamically the id into the post grids with Crocoblocks plugin.

The logic is **id of the page = id of the posts/custom posts**

But, I have a **pdf flipbook plugin** Dearflip which has already a shortcode to display a nice grid and I don't want to loose its functions like opening the flipbook in a modal.
It's a CPT with posts and categories.

I don't code myself, so I'd be happy if you can help me.

1/ I need **dflip_category** from this plugin to share the same **post category terms** like the others CPT so my **page category** checked can show the right contents dynamically.

- either I find a way to make this taxonomy showing into ACF so I can modify it to take terms from the post category - I found this https://www.acf-extended.com/features/modules/dynamic-taxonomies#existing-taxonomies but I mustn't do it right, it's not working
- either I add some hook into function.php but I'm not a coder so I have no idea how to do this

2/ I need to find a way to put the shortcode in the template with a **dynamic id** coming from the page category as it will be the same id. So I'm looking for a way to inject the page id dynamically into the shortcode.

The shortcode grid is like this **[dflip books="slug"]** and I'd like something like this **[dflip books="{insert_page_category_slug}"] [/dflip]**

- I found this https://www.isitwp.com/get-custom-field-value-with-shortcode/
- and this https://www.engagewp.com/how-to-insert-custom-fields-into-shortcodes/

Any help with the correct code would be awesome! I've been searching everywhere how to do it. It's out of my league.

Dearflip plugin CPT name : dflip  taxonomy: dflip_category
my Page (ACF) taxonomy : cat_id

Thanks in advance if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for now is : create a plugin re-creating the shortcode with the current page slug.
Naming the page slug like the category slug.
And manually add the category to dflip.

Couldn't find better so far.

```
// Disable direct access
defined('ABSPATH') or die('No script kiddies please!');

// use page slug to call dflip book in same slug dflip_category
add_shortcode('dflip_book_slug', 'shortcode_dflip_book_slug');
function shortcode_dflip_book_slug($atts = array(), $content = '', $tag)
{
    global $post;

    // default parameters (but filtered, only declared ones are passed)
    // $atts = shortcode_atts(array(
    //   'books' => $post->post_name
    // ), $atts, $tag);

    $atts = is_array($atts) ? $atts : array();

    if (array_key_exists('books', $atts)) {
        $atts['books'] = str_replace('%slug%', $post->post_name, $atts['books']);
    } else {
        // par défaut on passe le slug
        $atts['books'] = $post->post_name;
    }

    $atts_str = array();
    foreach ($atts as $key => $value) {
        $atts_str[] = $key . '="' . str_replace('"', '\"', $value) . '"';
    }

    $shortcode = '[dflip ' . implode(' ', $atts_str) . ']' . $content . '[/dflip]';
    return do_shortcode($shortcode);
}
```